# CKEditor and Jinja templates (console errors)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, jinja2

I'm using **CKEditor** in my flask app to give users WYSIWYG in my text fields, and I'm loading the script in the `base.html` jinja template.

However, I get console errors in the templates where I **don't** have a text field:

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-incorrect-element. 
Object { element: "description" }
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an empty block in my base.html instead of the script:

```
{% block CKEditor_js %}
{% endblock CKEditor_js %}
```

Then I added the script in a block at the bottom of the pages I need the script:

```
{% block CKEditor_js %}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/cke.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock CKEditor_js %}
```

And finally a very small JS file, in this case cke.js, with just:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("description");
```